# Insert data to another table after saving it to another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Sorry for the title, I didn't know what it should be.

To the point, the situation is as follows:
I insert data to one table `schedule`:

```
class ScheduleController extends Controller {
    public function saveSchedule(Request $request) {
        $schedule = new Schedule();
        $schedule->value = $request->value;
        $schedule->comment = $request->comment;

        $schedule->save();
    }
}
```

Now I would like to save some of this data (from the same request) into the second table `schedule_wh_relation`, something like this:

```
$relation = new Schedule_wh_relation();
$relation->schedule_id = $schedule->id;
$relation->comment = $request->comment;

$relation->save();
```

The question is how to achieve this? These data are to be closely related, the only idea that comes to my mind is to use a separate function in a different controller but calling a controller in another controller is not a good practice.

Comment: You can just add the code after the $schedule->save();

Comment: Even the first modification of your entity should not be placed in the controller directly - but if you have the first one there already (and not in a seperate service), why not put it into the very same method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make both save operations inside the same function

```
class ScheduleController extends Controller {
    public function saveSchedule(Request $request) {
        // create Schedule
        $schedule = new Schedule();
        $schedule->value = $request->value;
        $schedule->comment = $request->comment;

        $schedule->save();

        // create Schedule_wh_relation
        $relation = new Schedule_wh_relation();
        $relation->schedule_id = $schedule->id;
        $relation->comment = $request->comment;

        $relation->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created the relationship in your models you can do this

```
public function saveSchedule(Request $request) {
    $schedule = new Schedule();
    $schedule->value = $request->value;
    $schedule->comment = $request->comment;
    $schedule->save();
    
    $relation = new Schedule_wh_relation();
    $relation->associate($schedule);
    $relation->comment = $request->comment;
    $relation->save();
}
```